# php regular expression - how to separate repetition of subpattern in results

Tags: php, regex

I have following regular expression:

```
preg_match('/some text \d ([\d\,\s]*[A-Z0-9]\, [A-Za-ząćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ\s]*){0,5}/',$text,$results);
```

Inside there is subpattern: `([\d\,\s]*[A-Z0-9]\, [A-Za-ząćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ\s]*)` and I want to match it from 0 up to 5 times. But I would like to have each of the match of this subpattern to be separated from others in the `$result` array. - How I can do it?

For my result is (I changed strings for this example):

```
0 => string 'some text pattern1 pattern2 pattern3 pattern4 pattern5' (length=376)
1 => string 'pattern5'
```

So it matches subpattern 5 times but only last one is separated in array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible AFAIK. You would have to manually repeat the pattern in the regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do that with several steps.

According to your simplified string:

```
$text = "some text pattern1 pattern2 pattern3 pattern4 pattern5";
if (preg_match('/^some text /', $text)) {
    $text = preg_replace('/^some text /', '', $text);
    preg_match_all('/(pattern\d)/', $text, $m);
    print_r($m);
}
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => pattern1
            [1] => pattern2
            [2] => pattern3
            [3] => pattern4
            [4] => pattern5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => pattern1
            [1] => pattern2
            [2] => pattern3
            [3] => pattern4
            [4] => pattern5
        )

)
```